# IQueryable Select returns 0 records

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, ria, iqueryable

Hello I am failry new to silverlight and C# and have a program that utilizes the RIA techinique of using data. I am having problems with selecting a single column from my datasource. I am trying to use the value of that column to populate a single series in my chart.

On my UI I have a Grid and a bar chart.
I am able to populate my Grid by using:

```
DomainContext ctx = new DomainContext();
ListingGrid.ItemsSource = ctx.v_IQ_Flashes;
ctx.Load(ctx.Get_Table1());
```

That populates my datagrid with all(*) fields from my table Table1

Now I want to populate a single series on my chart with just one column from that chart.
Using the following code yeilds a return value of 0 (which is incorrect). What am I doing wrong?

```
var slot = ctx.v_IQ_Flashes.Where(e => e.Year == t_year).Select(e => e.Win );
var sum_ret_slot = slot.Sum();
decimal sum_slot = sum_ret_slot.Value;
```

Note that all values, (`Slot`, `sum_ret_slot`, `sum_slot`) are all 0. I used the debugger to verify that these are indeed being called and that their values are all 0.

Comment: Does removing the filter (`Where`) result in ... results?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you aren't actually getting anything from your `Where` clause.

Does removing the where clause cause it to work, it so I would evaluate that and determine why that isn't matching any records.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Unfortunately removing the where clause yielded the same result (0):
I am also including the following:
using BusinessApplication.Web.Services;
using BusinessApplication.Models;
using System.Linq;

Comment: @James then you aren't actually getting anything. hrmm

Comment: aye its very odd. I am using the same exact table to populate the datagrid, and its populating with over 500 records. Im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with msarchet - check the value of your t_year variable - are there any rows which actually match your Where predicate?

Do you get results if you change the code to:

```
var slot = ctx.v_IQ_Flashes.Select(e => e.Win );
var sum_ret_slot = slot.Sum();
decimal sum_slot = sum_ret_slot.Value;
```

Or do you get results if you change the code to:

```
var slot = ctx.v_IQ_Flashes.Where(e => e.Year == 2010).Select(e => e.Win );
var sum_ret_slot = slot.Sum();
decimal sum_slot = sum_ret_slot.Value;
```

Comment: In both of those cases I get 0 results. Maybe I am calling this incorrectly?

This code lies within my revenue_class.cs file.

I have main.xaml main.xaml.cs and rev.cs

At least its good news that I am doing the LINQ correctly but it is probably my lack of knowledge of the entire environment.

Comment: It sounds like maybe this line - `ctx.Load(ctx.Get_Table1());` - is rather important!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add code of sum_slot getting?
If you do it consequentially with loading, zero results are right cause ctx.Load(ctx.Get_Table1()) is async operation and if next your step is filter, data is not loaded yet.

I think, first way to make this code right - add filter to callback

ctx.Load(ctx.Get_Table1(), ()=>{//get sum_slot }, null);

Second way - apply filter to query:

ctx.Load(ctx.Get_Table1().Where(e => e.Year == t_year)) - context will load filtered items.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I really appreciate it, Mind my ignorance. I'm trying to get the Sum for no other purpose than to just have 1 record. 
I created a new table called 'test' and it only has 1 record so I did away with the sum.
However, Trying your second approach, how am I to assign that value to a variable?
I tried var test_var = ctx.Load(ctx.GetTest_tblQuery().Where(e => e.ID > 0).Select(e=>e.test));
but I am getting an error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'BusinessApplication.Web.test_tbl'

Comment: In this case try ctx.Load(ctx.GetTest_tblQuery().FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID > 0)). Domain service method GetTest_tbl() must return IQueryable<test>